# {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}

Tags: angular, webapi

(Get Post And delete working but the Put is not workin ..Why? below the error 
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}

```
 empObj = new Employee();
```

onUpdate() {

```
 this._empService.updateEmployee(this.empObj).subscribe(res => {
  this.message = "data updated successfully";

})
```

}

```
enter code here
```

updateEmployee(employee:Employee):Observable {

```
var url = "https://localhost:44382/api/UserTables/";
return this._http.put<number>(url, employee.Id)
```

}

Comment: Do you have the backend code? It says the backend doesn't define PUT on endpoint `/api/UserTables/`

Comment: Also, please reformat the code in your question

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is on the API side, not with the front. That message is saying that no one has implemented an endpoint for PUT at the backend side. And, if someone fixes that, heshe'll probably follow the convention for PUT, which states that the unique identifier must be the last part of the URL:

```js
updateEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<number> {
  const url = `https://localhost:44382/api/UserTables/${employee.Id}`;

  // Are you sure the return of PUT will a number?
  return this._http.put<number>(url, employee)
}
```

If you're trying to create a new user (which I think it's not the case here), you should be using POST (purely per definition => PUT is considered **idempotent[1]**, POST isn't):

```js
createEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<Employee> {
  const url = `https://localhost:44382/api/UserTables;
  return this._http.post<Employee>(url, employee);
}
```

**[1] idempotent:** When using PUT, if you repeat the *same* request (updating the same fields with the same field values on the same database entry) several times, the result should be the same - not considering eventual auditing info. On the other hand, if you repeat the same POST request N times, you will, potentially, create N new entries on the database.